# Swift - set clickable area on UIImageview

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

How could I define a clickable area on a UIImageview in swift ?

This area as to be fixed on the image even if I zoom or drag it.

Comment: Just app tap Gesture on Imageview and find touch location. then check that touch location is within your specified area or not. If it is within area, do what ever you want otherwise just ignore and do nothing.

Comment: Just like this... add a gestureReconizer ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35859244/how-to-make-whole-call-out-tappable/35859573#35859573

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the same technique as I recommended in this answer, add a gesturereconizer:

[How to make whole call out tappable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35859244/how-to-make-whole-call-out-tappable/35859573#35859573)

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a button to the image via programatically (IBuilder doesn't allow that)
2. Set userInteractionEnabled = true on imageView
3. Set the button either via AutoLayout or using springs and struts approach to resize with imageview.